# Stop .click function if user clicks many times

Tags: javascript, click

How to stop `.click` function if user clicks too many times? 
My code:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#bg').fadeToggle('200');
});
```

[jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexSotona/1dc8u7ms/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're asking this because the `fadeToggle` animation isn't behaving.

You can control running/queued animations with [`.stop([bool], [bool])`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Answer (score 2):

After more than 5 clicks it wil stop executing the function: http://jsfiddle.net/1dc8u7ms/1/

```
  var counter = 0;
    $('button').click(function() {
        if(counter > 5){return};
        $('#bg').fadeToggle('200');
        return counter++;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it using `one`

```
$( "#foo" ).one( "click", function() {
 $('#bg').fadeToggle('200');
});
```

See [DOC](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var maxclicks = 5,
    clicks = 0,
    handler = function() {
        if(clicks < maxclicks){
            $('#bg').fadeToggle('200');
            clicks++;
        }    
        else{
            console.log('You have reached the limit of '+ maxclicks + ' clicks.');
            $('button').off('click',handler)
        }

    };

$('button').on('click',handler);
```